# Admin panel for multiple projects

Tags: java, database, postgresql, database-design

In our company we have some projects, they all have in common approximately 70%. So admin panel for them is almost identical.

Our management want to have 1 admin panel for all the projects.
For example they want to see all users from all projects in one list, with possibility to filter them.
All projects have separate database.

How to handle this situation? Should we select + union from all databases? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: You could use foreign tables in a central database that combines the information from the other databases. See e.g. [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189654)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name will this work if we have 2 databases with users table each, and we need to unify these 2 tables in our admin panel?